# Slide trigger from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this for a slide trigger from top to bottom but on click my button is not moving from the top and the content is falling before button. I want as the content and my button to fall together.

Here you have my code for this.

HTML

```
<section class="drawer">
        <header class="clickme">Click Me</header>
           <div class="drawer-content">

               CONTENT HERE    

           </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.drawer {
    height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}

.drawer > header {
    background: url(../img/UP-Discover.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 77px;
    margin-left: 30%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.drawer-content {
    background: #fff;
    padding-top: 22px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 742px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 10px;
    border-color: #000;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('.drawer').slideDrawer({
        showDrawer: false,
        // slideTimeout: true,
        slideSpeed: 500,
        slideTimeoutCount: 3000,
    });
});
```

EDIT: This is the plugin that I am using. It was based on bottom. If I place it in bottom it will slide together.

```
(function(e) {
    var t = {
        init: function(n, r) {
            if (n.showDrawer == true && n.slideTimeout == true) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    t.slide(r, n.drawerHiddenHeight, n.slideSpeed)
                }, n.slideTimeoutCount)
            } else if (n.showDrawer == "slide") {
                t.slide(r, n.drawerHiddenHeight, n.slideSpeed)
            } else if (n.showDrawer == false) {
                t.hide(n, r)
            }
            e(".clickme").on("click", function() {
                t.toggle(n, r)
            })
        },
        toggle: function(n, r) {
            e(r).height() + n.borderHeight === n.drawerHeight ? t.slide(r, n.drawerHiddenHeight, n.slideSpeed) : t.slide(r, n.drawerHeight - n.borderHeight, n.slideSpeed)
        },
        slide: function(t, n, r) {
            e(t).animate({
                height: n
            }, r)
        },
        hide: function(t, n) {
            e(n).css("height", t.drawerHiddenHeight)
        }
    };
    e.fn.slideDrawer = function(n) {
        var r = this.children(".drawer-content"),
            i = parseInt(r.css("border-top-width"));
        drawerHeight = this.height() + i;
        drawerContentHeight = r.height() - i;
        drawerHiddenHeight = drawerHeight - drawerContentHeight;
        var s = {
            showDrawer: "slide",
            slideSpeed: 100,
            slideTimeout: true,
            slideTimeoutCount: 5e3,
            drawerContentHeight: drawerContentHeight,
            drawerHeight: drawerHeight,
            drawerHiddenHeight: drawerHiddenHeight,
            borderHeight: i
        };
        var n = e.extend(s, n);
        return this.each(function() {
            t.init(n, this)
        })
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You don't have a `button`. I can see you have a `header` tag with click me but that doesn't have the `.click()` event in your jQuery either. Think of the page as a dummy, it will do exactly what you ask it to with the correct instructions, without instructions it will do nothing because it knows nothing, hence *programming*.

Comment: have a look on my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to position your absolutely positioned drawer. Currently, it's just absolute. It's out of the flow of elements, but you need it "docked" to the bottom so that it's size, when it changes, starts bottom up.

I put together a fiddle with your code and some CSS liberties of my own. I also updated your header to have something in it to click. What @NewToJS was pointing out is that you had a header but nothing to click in it.

CSS for position:

```
.drawer {
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: 700px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/eaxkmh73/

***Edited***: I also forgot to mention you need to be careful with your heights. Part of the CSS liberties I took, aside from changing colors and playing with borders :), was to adjust the drawer and drawer-content heights. As they were, with an absolutely positioned drawer, when it grew the clickable header moved up past the top of the visible area. Obviously this means you can't click it closed. So, make sure you adjust your heights appropriately to keep items in view.

Also, in the future it is very helpful to put together one of these Fiddles yourself and provide the link with your question. That way, we can see exactly what you are experiencing and we can work off of that instead of putting together our own.

**Update**: After your latest comment I looked at what the script was doing and it looks fairly straight forward. Enough to do on your own with a simple DIY script. I am not sure if there is an advanced piece of functionality you need, but if not, the two Fiddles below offer optional approaches: One toggling a class for CSS transition; one for using jQuery slideToggle.

CSS Transition: http://jsfiddle.net/ceh0t3vv/3/

slideToggle: http://jsfiddle.net/11w2ufdr/2/

I left the option of supplying a 'data-target' attribute to the header if you wanted more flexibility in what you used for the content. But they can be simplified even further.

CSS simplified: http://jsfiddle.net/ceh0t3vv/4/

slideToggle simplified: http://jsfiddle.net/11w2ufdr/3/

Obviously the CSS is adjusted for each of those as well.

**Updated** Per latest comment, here is an example with positioning and margin applied to elements: http://jsfiddle.net/ceh0t3vv/5/

You could also combine a toggleClass and slideToggle, though you would need way more finesse than I put into this example. This is more of an example of why it might be better to position and z-index the actual drawer from the start, rather than toggle on open/close. Honestly, just less effort:
http://jsfiddle.net/11w2ufdr/4/

Comment: what I need is to do the same thing from top not from bottom.

Comment: there is any chance to change the z-index when is closed? because the way was build even if is closed in that area where it should to be opened I can't click or make anything. I was trying to use this but is going to change the z-index from beginning and my slide will open behind my elements. $(this).parent().children('.drawer-content').css("z-index", -1);

Comment: In the examples I gave I didn't account for anything else. But, you can easily set a z-index or positioning on it. It all depends on how you're using it. If it sits at the top all the time, position:absolute takes care of it. Then you just need top margin for your first element beneath it, for example.